# Running a recorded script on command line with Jmeter gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: performance, load-testing

I record the test script using Blaze Meter and run it on GUI of Jmeter,
it works fine.

But the same script when running on Command Line gives `Null Pointer`. Why would this be the case?

My second question is: Can I manipulate the Same Recorded script with CSV DataSet Config in order to Login with Multiple Users?

[image]

Here is Script In GUI in which I want to modify it with CSV DataSetConfig
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- To sort out this null pointer I would recommend taking the next steps:

  1. Temporarily enable logging of requests and responses details by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (located under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

     ```
     jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
     jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
     ```

     See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them.
  2. Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode
  3. Once test finishes open .jtl results file with [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and see requests and response details in it. Compare them with the ones you are getting in GUI mode. Additionally you may need to check *jmeter.log* file for any errors.
- To parameterize your test, if you need to use a new `userName` and you have a file with usernames list you can amend your request body like:

  ```
  {"userName" : "${__StringFromFile(/path/to/file/with/usernames.csv,,,)}"}
  ```

  Above [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) returns new line from the given file each time being called so each JMeter thread (virtual user) will send a new username

Comment: did the changes in user.properties file still the same 
null pointer exception and while using "${__StringFromFile(E:\Filename.csv)}" stil reads no data from CSV

Comment: The changes are not intended to resolve the problem, they configure JMeter to store more information in the .jtl results file so you could figure out the cause.

Comment: Nothing is getting recorded in my .jtl file because of the CSV file
Error in the console says 

FileServer: Stored: path to the file\filename.csv
and then it says 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File  Filename.csv must exist and be readable

Comment: It means that your csv file does not exist in the specified location, double check the path

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why I was not able to run the recorded script.

By default, the ramp up period is zero. When I set some value in the file, save it, and run it in Non GUI mode, it works.

I still haven't figured out the CSV issue.